# Get parameter(as Object) passed to method (using Spring AOP)

Tags: java, reflection, parameters

How can I get an Object from a method parameter of given type?
Assuming I have:

```
public void methodWithParameters(MyClass object, OtherClass otherObject) {
    //...
}
```

now i'm trying to get the object of MyClass type.

```
public Object getObject() {
    Method method = //get methodWithParameters
    Parameters[]parameters = method.getParameters();
        for (Parameter parameter : parameters) {
            if (parameter.getType().equals(MyClass)) {
                return //object that was passed to methodWithParameters
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a new instance of `MyClass`? If yes, you can use [`Class#newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--).

Comment: No i mean exactly that object that was passed to the method.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, because you cannot catch that object unless you invoke this method yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to catch a service (update) method execution with Spring AOP. My main goal is to compare the object that will be updated with the object that will be created after the update. That's why im trying to catch the parameter object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) to check that the object is of any particular type or not.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myclass= new MyClass();
        System.out.println("myclass instanceof MyClass: " + (myclass instanceof MyClass));
        System.out.println("myclass instanceof OtherClass: " + (myclass instanceof OtherClass));
        }
```

Output

```
myclass instanceof MyClass:true
myclass instanceof OtherClass:false
```

Comment: when i tried earlier to use instance of i got Unknown class error in my ide, that's why i have used the equals - nevermind.  Event that - thank You for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in a comment - i was trying to catch the argument with an aspect. The point is - my question was wrongly asked (sorry for that). The answer i was looking for is

```
JoinPoint#args()
```

Hope that can help someone in the future.